# Password format in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Ok I was writing some tests and I realized I could not possibly check the format of a password in rails in my model test. By format I mean a regex verifying that the password is at least 6 characters long etc. The reason I cannot do it is because I only store the secured hash of the password. Is this normal in most rails app? And is my only solution to check the password in my Integration tests?

Comment: How are you encrypting your passwords? If you are using Rails' has_secure_password then I believe you can do your validation on the :password field in the model itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the model you can have

```
validates_format_of :password, :with => /^(?=.\d)(?=.([a-z]|[A-Z]))([\x20-\x7E]){6,40}$/
```

Should work.

Comment: Hmm I am confused. I thought passwords were one way? Once they were hashed, there was no going back. Reading the source for SecuredPassword all I see is a `password=` method for setting the password. Does `attr_accessor :password` allow me access the password string?

Comment: Are you using any authentication gem? devise, authlogic?

Comment: Nope. Just has_secure_password

Comment: Can you check this article? I think it will help resolve the confusion. http://www.farbeyondprogramming.com/2011/05/rails-user-authentication-using-has_secure_password/  Let me know in case it does not help . Also take a look at how has_secure_password is implemented. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb#L42

Comment: Hmm from what I see here is that password should be an attr_accessor not attr_accessible...I did a little testing though and found out that after the object is lost the password can no longer be accessed.